# Add copy-append and cut-append to Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, copy-paste, text-editing, copy

Is it possible to do a *'copy-append'* or *'cut-append'* operation in Notepad++?

(means, copy/cut current selection or line if nothing selected, and append it to the copy/paste buffer instead of replacing the copy/paste buffer)

Useful for quickly gathering occasional lines in a file for pasting later, without having to jump back and forth to the paste location.

Or, if not, has anyone made a plugin that can add this functionality? I got used to having this several editors back (can't remember which one now) and really miss it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to **copy or cut lines** then simply *bookmark the lines you want* with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, or with a left click on that line, right beside the line number. After that go to menu *Search > Bookmark > Cut/Copy Bookmarked Lines*. You can also inverse the bookmarks to copy the unmarked lines, or remove the lines

[image: Notepad++ bookmark feature]

---

Another method is the mark feature. For example to copy all lines that contain *"copy*" then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> (or open menu *Search > Mark*) and mark with the regex `.*copy.*`, then click ***Copy Marked Text***

[image: Mark lines containing "copy"]

This works best if you have some *pattern* that can be **searchable** so a regex can be quickly applied. But you can also use it to mark normal phrases/paragraphs/sentences... because you can mark more patterns and they'll still be kept in the marked collection until you clear. For example select one sentence, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, select Mark All, select another sentence then repeat the above steps

This can also be used to quickly bookmark lines as you can see the *Bookmark line* checkbox in the *Mark* dialog

Here's another example to copy lines that doesn't contain the word "copy"

[image: Mark lines not containing "copy"]

Regex is a huge topic so if you don't know it you'll need to spend some time to learn it with [some](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/searching/#regular-expressions) [tutorials](https://regextutorial.org/), for example [this one](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html). Once you know it, it'll be extremely useful in finding and replacing texts

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Both the bookmarking and the search-marking. I always wondered what that little dot is that appears if you click there by mistake...

Comment: me too. Previously I though that was a debug break point but I couldn't find how to debug code directly in Notepad++. Note that you can mark multiple times and the mark points will still stay there

Answer (score 1):

- Go to Edit. Select Clipboard History
- Start copying/cutting. The texts you copied/cut will be on listed on the Clipboard History
- Double-click on a copied/cut text to paste it.

Comment: Sort of does what I want... fewer keypresses than copy/pasting one at a time, but still many more than what I got used to. Imagine scrolling through a file with a million lines, grabbing say a hundred lines one at a time by jumping forward using paging/search etc to find each one.